# Ruby: How to add two lines at once to a csv?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a list of items and a script which generates two lines of csv for each item.
May I add two lines at once to csv generator? I want something like this:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  items.each do |item|
    csv << rows(item)
  end
end

def rows(item)
  return \
    ['value1', 'value2', 'value2'],
    ['value3', 'value4', 'value5']
end
```

But `csv <<` can't receive two lines at once.

Now my the best code is:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  items.each do |item|
    rows(item).each { |row| csv << row } 
  end
end
```

**Update:** Now the best code without adding two line at once looks like:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  items.
    flat_map(&method(:rows)).
    each(&csv.method(:<<))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << items.flat_map(&method(:rows))
end
```

Comment: This doesn't generate clean CSV string, but rather something like that: `"[""value1"", ""value2"",`... (tested on Ruby 2.2.4)

Comment: I like an idea with `&method(:rows)` but the code gives wrong result.

Comment: @IlyaLavrov  You can make it work by doing `items.flat_map(&method(:rows)).each(&csv.method(:<<))`, but your version (from the question) is IMO soo much more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#push` or `Array#append` work the same way, and can take multiple arguments. **Edit**: As it turns out, `CSV.generate` yields a `CSV` object which has neither of those methods.

You can also do it like this:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  items.each do |item|
    r = rows(item)
    csv << r[0] << r[1]
  end
end
```

Comment: [`CSV`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) object doesn't have `append` method

Comment: @TeWu Thanks, I didn't notice.